# Decorate python method with optional argument

Tags: python, decorator

I have a Python class with many methods with signature:

```
def select_xxx(self, arg1 , arg2 , .. argn, intersect = False)
```

I.e. the methods have a varying (1-3) number of positional arguments, and an optional argument intersect with default value False. I would like to decorate all of these methods with a decorater which will insepect the value of the intersect parameter and take different actions accordingly. My current approach is something like this:

```
def select_decorator(select_method):

  def select_wrapper( self , *args, intersect = False , **kwargs)
     if intersect:
        # Special init code for intersect == True
        select_method( self , *args , **kwargs)
     else:
        # Normal call path for intersect == False 
        select_method( self , *args , **kwargs)

  return select_wrapper  

@select_decorator
select_xxx( self , arg1 , arg2 , intersect = False)
```

But getting the optional argument intersect into the *args and **kwargs mix inside the decorator is currently no joy. I could sacrifice the **kwargs functionality if that makes the problem easier to solve. Any suggestions?

Joakim

Comment: If you need more help with decorators and annotations see my blog post here. http://blog.mattalcock.com/2013/1/5/decorates-and-annotations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that intersect will always be passed as keyword argument. In which case you could simply do this inside you decorator

```
def select_decorator(select_method):

  def select_wrapper( self , *args, **kwargs):
     intersect = kwargs.has_key('intersect') and kwargs['intersect']
     if intersect:
        # Special init code for intersect == True
        select_method( self , *args , **kwargs)
     else:
        # Normal call path for intersect == False 
        select_method( self , *args , **kwargs)
  return select_wrapper
```

Comment: `or False` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Don't use `has_key`, it was deprecated in Python 2.x and removed from Python 3.x. Either use the `get` method: `intersect = kwargs.get('intersect', False)` or use `in` to test `'intersect' in kwargs and kwargs['intersect']`